# ¿Como crear un vector que cuente cuantas veces aparecen cada término en otro vector y agrupe el resto?

Tags: r

Tengo el vector generado con "rep(letters, times = 26:1)".
Necesito crear otro que cuente las veces que aparecen las cinco letras más frecuentes y que agrupe el resto en "otros". ¿Cual sería la metodología para hacer un TOP N en estos casos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que en R base la clave está en utilizar las funciones `head()` y `tail()`, de la siguiente manera:

```
# Creamos el vector
vector <- rep(letters, times = 26:1)
    
frecuencias <- table(vector) # Contamos las frecuencias por cada categoría
n <- 5 # Fijamos el número de categorías en los primeros n-lugares
num.categorias <- length(frecuencias) # 'Preguntamos' cuántas categorías hay
primeras <- head(frecuencias, n) # Contamos las primeras categorías
resto <- tail(frecuencias, num.categorias - n) # Contamos el resto
resto <- sum(resto) # Sumamos los elementos del resto    
frecs <- c(primeras, otras = resto) # Agrupamos las primeras y el resto
print(frecs)
> a     b     c     d     e  otras 
> 26    25    24    23    22   231
```

Answer (score 1):

Quizás una manera de abordar esto sería utilizando la librería `dplyr`. No se si entendí del todo tu pregunta, pero acá tienes dos ejemplos que podrían ayudar. El primero crea un vector con aquellas letras que se repiten más de 5 veces. Y el segundo ejemplo, crea un dataframe con el vector, y despues crea que una nueva columna status para indicar que letra en este caso es del grupo top 5 o del grupo otros.

```
library(dplyr)
```

#### Ejemplo 1

```
data.frame(
    columna1 = rep(letters, times = 26:1) 
  ) %>% 
  group_by(columna1) %>% 
  summarize(frequencia = n()) %>% 
  filter(frequencia > 5) %>% 
  select(columna1) %>% 
  pull()

 "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u"
```

#### Ejemplo 2

```
data.frame(
  columna1 = rep(letters, times = 26:1) 
) %>% 
  group_by(columna1) %>% 
  summarize(frequencia = n()) %>% 
  mutate(
    status = ifelse(frequencia > 5, "top_5", "Otros") 
  )

columna1 frequencia status
   <chr>         <int> <chr> 
 1 a                26 top_5 
 2 b                25 top_5 
 3 c                24 top_5 
 4 d                23 top_5 
 5 e                22 top_5 
 6 f                21 top_5 
 7 g                20 top_5 
 8 h                19 top_5 
 9 i                18 top_5 
10 j                17 top_5
```

Comment: El segundo caso es el que mas se asemeja. ¡Muchas gracias! Pero en ese caso, como podría tomar el vector que he creado (o data.frame) y crear otro que cuente las veces que aparecen las cinco letras más frecuentes y que agrupe el resto en otros.

Comment: El segundo ejemplo se hace cargo de esa situación. Lo único distinto que el vector usado en el ejemplo, la frecuencia de las letras es siempre mayor a 5 para todas. Si tratas con otro vector o dataframe donde la frequencia de la variable es menor a 5, el código del segundo ejemplo, asignará esta variable en la categoría otros.